# Create a google spreadsheet in same folder as current file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a google form script that I want to create a spreadsheet in the same folder as the form.

```
  var thisFileId = form.getId();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(thisFileId)
  
  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(spreadsheetName);
  var spreadsheetID = spreadsheet.getId();
  var spreasheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetID);
  spreasheetFile.moveTo(parentFolder);
```

I get an error on **the last line** :

> "Exception: Invalid argument: parent.mimeType"

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. Can you replace `spreasheetFile.moveTo(parentFolder);` with `parentFolder.addFile(spreasheetFile);` just to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: @Marios From `I have a google form script that I want to create a spreadsheet in the same folder as the form.`, I thought that `form` in OP's script might be Google Form. In this case, the same error occurs. I thought that the situation, that when ID except for the folder ID is used for `DriveApp.getFolderById(id)`, no error occurs, is also the issue.

Comment: You are saying that the folder is the Forms ID. Have you tried setting the folder ID directly in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create new Spreadsheet to the same folder with `form.getId()`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, about the variable name `form` of `form.getId()`, if `form` is the Google Form, `form.getId()` is the file ID of Google form. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- In order to put the new Spreadsheet to the same folder with `form`, it is required to retrieve the parent folder of `form`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(thisFileId)
```

##### To:

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId).getParents().next();
```

#### Note:

- It seems that when ID except for the folder ID is used for `DriveApp.getFolderById(id)`, no error occurs.

#### Reference:

- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)

Comment: This worked thanks, I thought getFolderById() gave the parent folder of the file by the file Id, but it just gives the folder by the folder Id which, in hindsight, makes a lot of sense haha.

Comment: I posted a followup questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562454/creating-a-spreadsheet-file-in-a-folder-without-using-auth-drive-scope), I'd appreciate any help.