# Creating a spreadsheet file in a folder without using auth/drive scope

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385188/create-a-google-spreadsheet-in-same-folder-as-current-file) before on creating a file and moving it to a folder, but now as I'm moving to publish this simple add-on I'm having issues with the auth/drive scope needed to move a file. auth/drive is a sensitive scope and I'd have to go through a review process just to publish. I tried changing the scope to auth/drive.file but apparently that doesn't apply to the moveTo method.

I find it frustrating that I have to jump through hoops just to create a file in the correct location. Are there any other ways to move create a file in a folder that doesn't require sensitive or restricted scopes?

Here is the function

```
function createSpreadsheet(form){
  var spreadsheetName = [form.getTitle() + " Results"];
  var thisFileId = form.getId();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId).getParents().next();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(spreadsheetName);
  var spreadsheetID = spreadsheet.getId();
  var spreasheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetID);
  spreasheetFile.moveTo(parentFolder);
  return spreadsheet;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to narrow the scopes of your Google Apps Script.

  - You want to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` for this.

#### Modification points:

In this case, when Drive service is used, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is required to be used. So in order to narrow the scopes, I would like to propose to use Drive API instead of Drive service.

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the parent folder ID of "thisFileId".

   - In this case, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` is used.
2. Create new Spreadsheet to the specific folder.

   - In this case, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is used.
   - The Spreadsheet is created and moved to the specific folder using the method of "Files: insert" by one API call.
3. Retrieve Spreadsheet object.

   - In this case, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` is used.

This flow is the same process with your script. When above flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function createSpreadsheet(form){
  var spreadsheetName = [form.getTitle() + " Results"];
  var thisFileId = form.getId();
  
  // 1. Retrieve the parent folder ID of "thisFileId".
  // In this case, the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly" is used.
  var folderId = Drive.Files.get(thisFileId).parents[0].id;
  
  // 2. Create new Spreadsheet to the specific folder.
  // In this case, the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" is used.
  var spreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({title: spreadsheetName, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: folderId}]}).id;
  
  // 3. Retrieve Spreadsheet object.
  // In this case, the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" is used.
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
}
```

#### Note:

- **This sample script is for the script in your question. So when you are using the methods for using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` in your other part, this script might not be useful. Please be careful this.**
- From `form.getTitle()` and `form.getId()`, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms` might be required to be included. Please be careful this. And also, when you are using other methods for using other scopes, please include them.
- The Spreadsheet is created with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, the Spreadsheet can be used by the application using the scope. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

Answer (score 0):

**Drive API is an API with restricted scopes.**

If you look at the [list of restricted scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#restricted-scopes) for the Drive API, you can see that the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is indeed **not present** in this list to be a **restricted scope** but depending on your application, it may qualify as a **sensitive scope**.

In order to check this, you can add the scope to your project via the Google Cloud Console and see if there will be a lock icon.

However, retrieving a folder and moving the file **will** require the use of other scopes which **are** part of the list, hence the verification process **will be necessary**.

There are also exceptions to the verification process; specifically for the add-on you are mentioning, these might apply:

1. If you want to deploy the add-on solely for **internal use** which means that the add on will be used only by people in your Google Workspace or Cloud Identity organization.
2. If you want to use the add-on **domain wide** which means that the add on will be used only by Google Workspace enterprise users within the domain.

For the whole list of exceptions, you can check this [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#exceptions-ver-reqts).

#### Reference

- [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).